General questions concering column generation
I have a basic question about the Dantig-Wolfe reformulation. How do I know which constraints go into the master problem and which into the subproblem(s)? As I understand it, constraints that connect everything (demand constraints, for example) go into the MP and the rest into the SP(s). And how do I know how to subdivide my objective function of the compact model? What goes into the objective function of the MP and what into that of the SP? And how do the dual values flow into it?

Marco Lübbecke has written a very detailed article about Column Generation, where he explains the algorithm and how it works very well.

What goes into the master problem (MP) vs the subproblems (SP) is a choice you make. Usually, it depends on the structure of the problem. For instance, if the constraint matrix is block-diagonal, except for some rows, those rows typically go in the MP and each block becomes a SP.
But it can be more complicated than that, and figuring out a good Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition is sometimes more of an art.
As for dual variables, there is no short way to explain this. Like @Abdellah, I suggest reading a paper on column generation.
